# Boiler Maintenance - hiring somebody to do it

Tags: heating, boiler

The gas boiler in our home is 9 years old and it has never been serviced. I feel it is due for service. One local Plumber / Heating company says they will do the work we want
done for $329. I consider that price a bit high but okay. Another company says they will do the work for $349 but there is another option. They will sell us a service contract for $209 which includes free annual maintenance and 15% off all other work. I told them that something seems wrong to me because the service contract include $349 worth of work. The person I spoke to told me that he did not set prices.

I was told that when I sign up for the service contract, I would need to pay. That is, before any work was done. Is that a red flag? Is there something I am missing? What should I do?

Comment: Your question involves cost and "what you should do". We don't really handle either of those here. Maybe reformulate to just ask why an ongoing contractual arrangement would cost less for an initial visit that a one-time service. Skip the numbers.

Comment: I'd imagine that if you were to remove the "actual price" and substitute it with "price x" and "lower price y", you'd probably get a better response and the question reopened. Actual $£€ numbers tend to get questions closed because they can vary so much by region and even by company you talk to (as you've noted), and tend to get questions closed.

Answer (score 7):

The two higher quotes are for one time deal, they might never get any more money from you.

The contract is yearly charge and is hoping for major or minor piece to fail (15% off) and they get the money to fix it.

Ask friends/neighbours for recommendations of service companies they use.

Heating devices are recommended (or required by local law) to be checked every year or two.  Usually a good cleaning and check (most important) for how it is burning.  Might not take long for a person who knows what they are doing, but you are paying for knowledge (hopefully).

As ask by comment, most heating devices/appliances do wear and have dirt/soot build up.  Adjustments can change and cracks may happen.  Draft for the chimney/exhaust can change due to not being cleaned.  Any of these things can make the burn not be normal/proper and cause a build up of carbon monoxide gas in the home.  Stories in the news every year about people dying every year.  A few get lucky and just almost die because of this.

Comment: What happens such that a heating device needs to be checked for how it is burning?  I've seen that they can start generating CO - hopefully you have a CO detector - but in general what is the cause of that?

Comment: @FreshCodemonger   Wear, dirt/soot build up, adjustments being off for air/gas, blockages, wrong or bad draft in the chimney, cracks in the burn chamber/device.  A good technician should check, clean and adjust everything except cleaning the chimney/exhaust pipe.  That is usually left to chimney sweeps.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger A few decades ago before we had CO alarms, my parents' furnace started giving them headaches when running. Turned out to be CO, leaking through a crack in the combustion chamber.

Comment: I did a quick search.  Seems like all combustion devices generate CO.  The typical issue is the heat exchanger cracks and blows CO back into house.  I had a heat exchange crack on a forced air but it just kept blowing out the pilot.  The once a year thing isn't a bad idea but should be secondary to working CO alarm, no guarantee it cracks close to the yearly inspection.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger Complete combustion of a hydrocarbon reduces it to CO2 and H20.  Incomplete combustion makes H2O + CO + soot (=sections of unburnt fuel).  There's one fewer oxygen in the combustion products, plus less combustion (soot) => incomplete combustion happens when you don't have enough oxygen, or can't use it all (too little heat/flowrate too fast = fuel doesn't have time to react).  A well designed *and adjusted* hydrocarbon burner (boiler, engine, etc) will have very little CO in the exhaust gasses.  Unfortunately you can't usually monitor boiler efficiency like you can your car's.

Answer (score 4):

It's not necessarily a red flag that they're asking you to pay for the service contract before any of its included maintenance is done. However, it's obvious that they're giving these generous discounts because there's something in it for them.

The cynical view is that the service contract may provide the following benefits *to the service company*:

- a chance to visit your home at least annually to do some dubious maintenance work (clean the dust bunnies, wax-and-shine the cabinet, etc) and find some "that's not included in the service contract" work to ask the customer to pay extra for
- opportunity to proactively schedule your maintenance in the spring and fall, providing a bit of work to keep the technicians busy so they won't bail and look for work with a different employer
- possibly you'll decline to have them come do the maintenance at the time they propose, forget all about it, and end up paying the annual fee for them to *do no work at all*
- hopefully, they'll be your first-and-only call when there's something you truly do need to have serviced

Answer (score 1):

> The gas boiler in our home is 9 years old and it has never been serviced.

And you are certainly not the only one in that situation.

The averages play out so that people who buy one-off maintenance have their boilers generally less well maintained than those who have an annual contract. Even if there are no broken parts, everything just takes more time:

- Parts have more accumulated combustion byproducts and require more cleaning time and chemicals.
- Valves and vents are more often in need of readjustment.
- Parts can be stuck or rusted together

The company selling an annual contract probably makes less profit in the first year, but more money in the coming years. And if you try to game the system by cancelling and resubscribing, they probably won't sell you another annual contract.